# Is tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter thread-safe?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to convert csv format dataset files to TFRecords parallelly. Is `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter` thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

I was also searching for the question. I found at it is not a thread safe method. I couldn't find any documentation for this answer but tried both multi threading process and single threading process instead on same data. The result was that multi threading approach creates a record file that throws an error while training and single threading approach creates a valid record file which of course runs fine while training but takes much longer time than multi threading during creation time. I hope this answer is helpful.

Comment: From review: Unless you provide more details on the root cause of this issue, this post is more suited to be a comment to the question instead of an answer (and just the second half of it). This means, this post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.